# Procurar objetos no mysql

Tags: mysql

Boa tarde,
Estou usando o WorkBeanch 6.3 e preciso pesquisar na base de dados MySql se determinada Coluna existe e qual a sua Tabela, preciso saber também se a determinada Coluna é usada em uma Procedure ou View, por exemplo em Sql Server faço assim;

```
      SELECT O.name as Tabelas 
        FROM syscolumns C 
  INNER JOIN sysobjects O ON C.id = O.id 
       WHERE c.name like '%idConta%'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você poderia tentar assim, onde no like passa o idConta

```
SELECT SPECIFIC_NAME FROM information_schema.routines WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION like '%idConta%'
```

Para descobrir definers de objetos, trabalhe na tabela 'information_schema', onde você consegue as informações dos objetos, você conseguirá muita coisa nela.
Abaixo, exemplos de select para descobrir os definers.

```
SELECT specific_name, routine_schema, routine_name, routine_type, definer FROM information_schema.routines WHERE definer = 'seu_user'; 

SELECT trigger_catalog, trigger_schema, trigger_name, definer FROM information_schema.triggers WHERE definer = 'seu_user';

SELECT table_catalog, table_schema, table_name, definer FROM information_schema.views WHERE definer = 'seu_user';
```